# Throwing an application exception causes TransactionalException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, exception, transactions

I am implementing an JEE7 web application. During my work i have found a problem with handling  my custom exceptions.

I edited my account's property to have a non-unique login field. Then i invoked the `AccountEditBean#editAccount()` to run the editing process. When the process comes to `AccountFacade#edit()` i can see (in debug) that `PersistenceException` is caught and my custom `NonUniqueException` is thrown. The problem is, the exception is not propagated out of the facade class and it is not handled in `AccountEditBean`. Instead of that `TransactionalException` occurs right after `throw`:

```
WARNING:   EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on
EJB ADMEndpoint, method: public void
pl.rozart.greatidea.adm.endpoints.ADMEndpoint.editAccount(pl.rozart.greatidea.entities.Account)
throws pl.rozart.greatidea.exceptions.BaseApplicationException
WARNING:   javax.transaction.TransactionalException: Managed bean with
Transactional annotation and TxType of REQUIRES_NEW encountered
exception during commit javax.transaction.RollbackException:
Transaction marked for rollback.
```

Additional information:
`NonUniqueException` extends `BaseApplicationException` , which is marked as `@ApplicationException(rollback=true)`.

Here's the code for the edit process:

AccountEditBean:

```
@Named(value = "accountEditBean")
@ViewScoped
public class AccountEditBean extends UtilityBean implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    ADMEndpointLocal admEndpoint;

    private Account account;

    public void editAccount() {
        try {
            admEndpoint.editAccount(this.account);
            Messages.addInfo(ACCOUNT_DETAILS_FORM, KEY_CHANGES_SUCCESS);
        } catch (NonUniqueException e) {
            Messages.addError(ACCOUNT_DETAILS_FORM, e.getMessage());
        } catch (BaseApplicationException e) {
            Messages.addFatal(ACCOUNT_DETAILS_FORM, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

ADMEndpoint:

```
@Stateful
@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
@TransactionTracker
public class ADMEndpoint extends LoggingStateBean implements ADMEndpointLocal, SessionSynchronization {

    @EJB(name = "ADMAccountFacade")
    private AccountFacadeLocal accountFacade;

    private Account account;

    @Override
    public void editAccount(Account account) throws BaseApplicationException {
        this.account.setLogin(account.getLogin());
        this.account.setEmail(account.getEmail());
        accountFacade.edit(this.account);
    }

}
```

ADMAccountFacade:

```
@Stateless(name = "ADMAccountFacade")
@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.MANDATORY)
@TransactionTracker
public class AccountFacade extends AbstractFacade<Account> implements AccountFacadeLocal {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void edit(Account account) throws BaseApplicationException {
        try {
            em.merge(account);
            em.flush();
        } catch (PersistenceException e){
            if(e.getMessage().contains(Account.CONSTRAINT_ACCOUNT_LOGIN_UNIQUE)){
                throw new NonUniqueException(NonUniqueException.MSG_NON_UNIQUE_ACCOUNT_LOGIN, e);
            }else{
                throw new BaseDatabaseException(BaseDatabaseException.MSG_GENERAL_DATABASE_ERROR, e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do you know what could be the cause of the problem? It occurs in every of my facades, with all the custom exceptions.

Comment: How do you call the accountFacade.edit(this.account) in editAccount method in ADMEndpoint class if you do not have account field?

Comment: Sorry, i just didn't paste it here. Now it should be clear. :)

Comment: Then Account parameter is useless in editAccount method because you never use it!

Comment: I hope now everything is clear. :)

Comment: I think you should change `@Transactional` to `@TransactionAttribute` because EJBs annotated with that.`@Transactional` is put on managedbean in java 7 not in EJBs...

Comment: Yes they can when you use injection (not in remote call) but it is not same in transaction handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change `@Transactional` to `@TransactionAttribute` because EJBs annotated with that. `@Transactional` is put on managedbean in java 7 not in EJBs...

I copied my comment here because i do not have enough points to squander :)

Comment: Thank you it did fix the problem. But isn't it like that:
`@Transactional` annotation is for CDI beans, and in JEE7 beans can be EJB and CDI at the same time?

Comment: Yes they can. managedbeans=cdi managed beans. I just wrote down briefly. As I mentioned above and (as I know) EJBs can be CDIs bean at the same time when we try to reach it not in remote call. So we use `@inject` instead of `@EJB` but it does not concern transaction handling.

Answer (score 0):

You are throwing an exception from a method whose invocation will be intercepted at runtime and additional logic wrapped around it:

- transaction management;
- exception handling.

Your exception cannot transparently jump over that logic, and the specification (probably) says a `TransactionalException` will be thrown, wrapping your original exception (again, *probably*---I am not that intimate with the details).

Comment: The strange thing is i did it exactly the same when i was implementing JEE6 application (Of course i used `@TransactionAttribute` instead of `@Transactional`) and my custom exception was propagated properly.

Comment: This change may actually be a good thing: one of the common pitfalls with EJB has been the inability to deserialize an exception, resulting in a serialization exception which masked out the original problem.